# Debugging generated java classes in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, mixins, auto-generate

I'm working on a project that is generating classes at runtime https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeAPI

Is it possible to debug the classes it generates at runtime with IntelliJ even though there are no, (incorrect) or multiple sources attached for the class?

For the classes that have partial sources I've tried debugging them, but all I end up stepping through is the incomplete sources if they exist. Is there a way to navigate the classes and view the decompiled sources while debugging?

Comment: You want to debug sources which don't exist on your local machine?

Comment: It doesn't have to be sources, can be .classes or bytecode. Looking into ways of adding instrumentation in order to add the partial sources / mixins however.

Answer (score 0):

If the library you are using has support for dumping the class files or source to disk, it should be possible to add the directory as a provided dependency to the module you are debugging.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206152289-Is-it-possible-to-debug-compiled-classes-instead-of-the-source-